# How do I parse this syntax in the ECMAScript specification?

Tags: javascript

From ECMA 262, 10.3.1 (http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3.1)

> During execution of ECMAScript code, the syntactic production
>   `PrimaryExpression : Identifier` is evaluated using the following
>   algorithm

How should I read the following expression?

```
PrimaryExpression : Identifer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the quoted expression recalls the (relevant) fragment of the language grammer defined fully in [Appendix 3](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-A.3)

in more detail, the term on the left, `PrimaryExpression` non-terminal, which can be, among other things, an `Identifier`;  Other parts of the of the language may require that a `PrimaryExpression` be "parsed here", which could be allowed to be an `Identifier`.  This linked section goes on to explain the algorith used for resolving an `Identifier` into a `PrimaryExpression`